# How can one encode data of different dimensions into a tensor in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm relatively new to Deep Learning. In my Deep Learning class our input was always images or vectors of numbers which fit a nice rectangular format. My question is: if you have data that doesn't fit into nice rectangular shapes, how do you combine them to go through a single feed-forward network? In my case, I am trying to encode all the information about a game for a reinforcement learning task. This will include a grid/matrix of data (similar to a chess board), as well as metadata like time remaining and other information that's not part of the board. The tensor that goes into my network needs to maintain the spatial relationship with the board, but not imply a spatial relationship with the metadata. Tips?

Comment: Have you ever heard of padding? You could manipulate input images in order to add bogus pixels just to make it become of the desired input size

Comment: You know that crossed my mind, it just seems like it would be a pretty weird hack for a problem I'm sure is fairly common.  Another example is when people have sound and images (video), how do they represent the sound with the video, surely it's not just some padding trick.

Comment: Padding is fairly common when handling text and I wouldn't be surprised if the same was applied to other data as well. Unfortunately, I've only got some experience with text, so I cannot give you more advices; without using padding, you would need to crop every image to the same fixed size, potentially losing a lot of information